# Access VBA - Identifying text

Tags: sql, string, ms-access, vba

Im trying to create a button to delete certain records in a subform. However im getting "syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'KEY_ID="1'.

I know what the problem is: The attribute is text therefore the value needs to be surrounded by single quotes. I just don't know how to write the VBA to accomplish this.

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
If Not (Me.subKey.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.subKey.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
    If MsgBox("Confirm Deletion?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        Dim strSql As String
        strSql = "DELETE FROM KEYS" & _
            " WHERE KEY_ID='" & Me.subKey.Form.Recordset.Fields("KEY_ID")
        Debug.Print strSql ' <- prints to Immediate window
        CurrentDb.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError

    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strSql = "DELETE FROM KEYS" & _
    " WHERE KEY_ID='" & Me.subKey.Form.Recordset.Fields("KEY_ID") & "'"
```

... though, mind you, using the quote as an ASCII character is safer, or at least more versatile or portable, when these kinds of things get more intensive.

```
strSql = "DELETE FROM KEYS" & _
    " WHERE KEY_ID=" & _
    Chr(32) & Me.subKey.Form.Recordset.Fields("KEY_ID") & Chr(32)
```

I'm not sure it's `Chr(32)` but I think that is correct.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I've been at this for sooo long.

Comment: The placement of quotation marks and '&' make very little sense to me :/

Comment: Your SQL is complete, as you said, except for the closing quote.  `& "'"` takes care of this.  Trouble-shooting step:  Run this code without the `Me.subKey` variable.  Just get it to run, then add the complications.  It should make sense by the time you're done.

Comment: Ohh I get it. It's the opening quote right before the WHERE that was throwing me off. I first though that this was the opening and the very very last quote at the end was closing - everything else was nested. I know see that were are actually 3 opening and closing sections (no nesting). Makes more sense now. Thank you.

Comment: I think Chr(39) is what you're after.  Chr(32) is the space character.

Comment: Yea that's what I used, 39 is correct. Sorry forgot to mention that. Thanks @grantnz

Comment: BTW, you could tidy this up a bit with a function to do the quoting.

Function Quote(value As String) As String
    Quote = "'" & value & "'"
End Function